# notepad++ macro don't work

Tags: macros, notepad++

I have a problem with notepad++ macro.

I use notepad++ v.6.4.3 and I defined about 50-60 macro, but when i tried call some, notepad++ mess the macro or write only part of them.

Also...where notepad++ write the user's macro? I search in %appdata%/notepad++ folder, in shortcuts.xml, but I found nothing...I tried also in shortcuts.xml in program/notepad++ folder, but the results is similar.

Weel...How can I do?

I must export the macro that I created and notepad++ don't write random things...

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please consider

- reporting the problem [as suggested on Notepad++ homepage](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/contribute/)
- [switching to another form of macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992699/add-a-new-command-to-notepad/22989832#22989832). Although I strongly prefer **AutoHotKey** (because it works in all applications across Windows platform), other options work well, too.

Answer (score 0):

One issue that tripped me up for a bit was caused by me trying to assign MY macro to a pre-existing key binding. Specifically, I recorded my macro, and then tried to assign it to Alt+1. However, Alt+1 was already bound to an intrinsic Notepad++ feature, so my macro never ran.

I hope this helps at least one person out there.